# How to configure mocha-sidebar to use ttypescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js, ts-node

I have a project with mocha tests that rely on [ts-nameof](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-nameof).

The mocha tests is supported by [Mocha sidebar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maty.vscode-mocha-sidebar) in VSCode.

When trying to refresh my tests (in the tests sidebar) I have a `ReferenceError: nameof is not defined`.

My understanding is that I have to setup Mocha sidebar to somehow use [ttypescript instead of typescript](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof/blob/master/packages/ts-nameof/setup/tsc.md) (like I did with VSCode).

I know this VSCode plugin rely on ts-node since they are asking to set the VS settings
`"mocha.requires": [ "ts-node/register" ]`.

I tried to look for a "tts-node" package (a ts-node like but for ttypescript), or what exactly is this "ts-node/register" and help me finding better keywords to search for, but didn't find an answer.

I tried to add "ttypescript" and "ts-nameof" in the mocha.requires, this didn't change anything.

I did find that ts-node can accept a [--compiler setting that could (maybe?) be ttypescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#user-content-configuration-options), however, I don't know how to provide it to the Mocha sidebar plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the ts-node & mocha codes and found there is no way to provide the ts-node --compiler argument from mocha.

However, I found a different way to so, in the settings.json, instead of using `"mocha.requires": [ "ts-node/register" ]` I use `"mocha.requires": [ "./ttypescript-register.js" ]`".

Then in the root of my project I created a file ttypescript-register.js with `require('./node_modules/ts-node/dist').register({compiler: "ttypescript"});`